# How to get Build time in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, build

I want to get the build time in VSCode, similar to one in sublime text [See here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEGRF.png) Is it possible to enable this in vscode?

Comment: write a small shell script that does the build and also time the duration, call this script from the build task

Comment: @rioV8 Can you help me how to do that?